# Why does the api gets called 2 times when using this service to cache the http request

Tags: angular

When the page loads for the first time or when you manually reload the page the api is called 2 times both get requests. 
 After that when you go to other components and come back to home via router links the api is not called again so it works but the only thing is that on refresh the api is called 2 times instead of 1.

Data Service

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient, HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
 import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

    public responseCache = new Map();

      constructor(private http: HttpClient, private handler: HttpBackend) {
        this.http = new HttpClient(this.handler);
       }

      getTimeZone(): Observable<any> {
        const URL = environment.BACKEND_HOST + 'api/timezone';
        const fromCache = this.responseCache.get(URL);
        if (fromCache) {
          return of(fromCache);
        }
        const response = this.http.get<any>(URL);
        response.subscribe(res => this.responseCache.set(URL, res));
        return response;
      }
```

Home Component
  How I am calling it

```
this.data.getTimeZone().subscribe((data: any)=> {
        this.timezones = data;
      })
```

Comment: can you share full code of Home Component ??

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of network tab of the request being call 2 times ?

Comment: First one could be OPTIONS request?

Comment: screenshot https://i.imgur.com/W5rSMFG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You `subscribe` to `response` once in `getTimeZone` and return `response` and then `subscribe` it again with `this.data.getTimeZone().subscribe(...)`. This is why it is called twice.

You can use `map()` or `tap()` pipeable operators in `getTimeZone` instead of subscribing to it:

```
getTimeZone(): Observable<any> {
    const URL = environment.BACKEND_HOST + 'api/timezone';
    const fromCache = this.responseCache.get(URL);
    if (fromCache) {
      return of(fromCache);
    }
    const response = this.http.get<any>(URL);
    return response.pipe(
          tap(res => {
               this.responseCache.set(URL, res)
           })
         );

  }
```

do/tap: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html